# ACC API - Project Endpoint - filter[type] does not use Contains search

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-construction-cloud

When using the filter[name] and filter[jobNumber] url parameters on the Projects GET endpoint, these work as contains which is indicated as the default in the reference. However, when using the filter[type] parameter it appears to only work as equals with the full value.

I tried several different values and only when the full and complete project Type is included does it return the expected results. Again, project name and job number work as expected.

Is this a design choice or is this an issue with the API itself?

Do I have for forcibly call the filterTextMatch parameter even though "contains" is the indicated default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is by design that both `filter[name]` and `filter[jobNumber]` accept a partial match based on the value of `filterTextMatch` that you provide. The default value: `contains`; other possible values are: `contains`, `startsWith`, `endsWith` and `equals`.

When it comes to the `filter[type]` parameter, the value has to be exactly equal to the exact project type. The possible values are provided by APS.